# How to allow overlaping of Images in gmail mail HTML

Tags: html, css, gmail, html-email

I'm sending some HTML formatted mails where I'm showing property images with their current statuses. There are some triangular status images overlapping to main property images which are getting distorted as MARGIN style property is not allowed in Gmail. Style properties like PADDING and POSITION are also not working. This mail is formatted in table based HTML.

I just want to place status tag images on to right bottom corner of the property images. Kindly help with some alternate solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You can't overlap foreground images, and you can't use multiple background images.

What you can do is use background images, with foreground images overlapping them.

The other alternative is to use one image, and replace the image on the back end as the status changes. If this happens a lot, you could generate them dynamically.

Comment: FYI. Gmail does not support background images.

Comment: It doesn't support them in CSS, but you can use a background attribute instead, which works fine. A whole article on getting background images to work in email clients: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3363/updated-applying-a-background-image-to-html-email/